# Can't send message to group chat

Tags: bash, imessage, osascript

I found a script that sends messages from the command line, but It won't work with my group chat with spacing and capitalization in the name.

```
#!/bin/sh
recipient="${1}"
message="${*:2}"
echo "$recipient"
cat<<EOF | osascript - "${recipient}" "${message}"
on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage}
   tell application "Messages"
       set targetService to 1st service whose service type = iMessage
       set targetBuddy to buddy targetBuddyPhone of targetService        
       send targetMessage to targetBuddy
   end tell
end run
EOF
```

when I run `./sendmessage "GROUP CHAT" "test"` it gives me 
`228:261: execution error: Messages got an error: Can’t get buddy id "7087805D-ED73-4DB9-81AB-7C964B98AB34:group chat". (-1728)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unforunately, it is not possible to send a message to a group chat with applescript by using the chat's name. To send to an existing group chat, you will instead need to obtain the chat's internal guid. There are 2 methods of doing this.

1. Extract it from the messages.app internal database, located on disk at `~/Library/Messages/chat.db`. It is the guid column under the chat table. If you have the group chat named it will be easy to find by display_name.
2. You can use an AppleScript handler for Messages with the `on chat room message received` handler to capture the ID when someone posts in that chat.

Once you have the guid (should in a format similar to `iMessage;+;chat831551415676550949`), your script can be modified to send to the ID instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
recipient="${1}"
message="${*:2}"
echo "$recipient"
cat<<EOF | osascript - "${recipient}" "${message}"
on run {targetChatID, targetMessage}
   tell application "Messages"
    set targetChat to a reference to text chat id targetChatID
    send targetMessage to targetChat
   end tell
end run
EOF
```

To send an image instead of text, replace the targetMessage with:

```
set ImageAttachment to POSIX file "File path here" as alias
```

Comment: Are you like specifically looking for all group chat files?

Comment: What do you mean by "all group chat files"?